# How to convert csv to a map using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, csv, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create a simple parsing util that converts a two-column CSV file and put it into a map.

```
public Map<String, String> getMapFromCSV(final String filePath) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))
                .map(line -> line.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(line -> line[0], line -> line[1]));
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a stream of strings, delimiting each line on a comma and transforming it into a string array, and finally mapping key to index 0 and value to index 1.

```
@Test
public void testGetMapFromCSV() throws IOException{
    actual = util.getMapFromCSV(filePath).get("AL");
    expected = "ALABAMA";

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

For some reason, when I run this test, the actual value is null. I ruled out invalid filePath because it's working fine in another unit test, and the key value is present in the CSV. I've been staring at it for a few hours now, figured maybe someone here could point out my error.

Also, I'm fairly new to Java 8, so if anyone knows a better/cleaner way of writing this, I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: You are leaking a file descriptor here. `Files.lines()` should be opened in a try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Is there whitespace in the file?

Comment: `null` may suggests that `map.get(key)` couldn't find `key` in map. Try printing entire map returned by `util.getMapFromCSV(filePath)`.

Comment: @fge doesn't collect() close the stream?

Comment: No it doesn't. It consumes all the elements but doesn't call `.close()`. You have to do it yourself. (by the way, it is `BaseStream` which implements `AutoCloseable`, and `Stream` extends `BaseStream`)

Comment: You might try filtering out empty lines before the split

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I added `lines.close()` and removed any whitespace from the csv and it works! Strange, considering the csv got parsed fine in my other method. Here's what it looks like:

```
public static Map<String, String> getMapFromCSV(final String filePath) throws IOException{

        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath));
        Map<String, String> resultMap = 
                lines.map(line -> line.split(","))
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(line -> line[0], line -> line[1]));

        lines.close();

        return resultMap;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Do you know of a way to do it with streams while removing duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

## Try-with-resources with `AutoCloseable`

As [commented by fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge), using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) makes this easier.

Here is the code from [your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36487868/642706) but using try-with-resources to automatically close a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) that is also [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). And some added SPACE characters for breathing room.

```java
public static Map<String, String> getMapFromCSV(final String filePath) throws IOException{

    try (
        Stream < String > lines = Files.lines( Paths.get( filePath ) );
    )
    {
        Map < String , String > resultMap = 
                lines.map( 
                         line -> line.split( "," ) 
                     )
                     .collect(
                         Collectors.toMap( line -> line[0] , line -> line[1] )
                     );
        return resultMap;
    }
    // The `Stream` named `lines` is automatically closed at this point by the try-with-resources.
}
```

When the `{…}` block of the try-with-resources ends, any resources opened in the `try` are automatically closed, in reverse order of their opening. This is true whether flow-of-control leaves the block gracefully upon completion, or abruptly due to an exception or a `return` (as seen in your code). See discussion on this Question, [*Try-with-resources and return statements in java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22947755/642706).

Answer (score 0):

*in a form that might be easier to read – with* `mapping`

```
public static Map<String, String> getMapFromCSV(final String filePath) throws IOException {
  try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
      return lines.collect(
        mapping(s -> s.split(","), toMap(k -> k[0], v -> v[1])));
  }
}
```